# how to add session user can vote only

Tags: javascript, php

This is my complete voteing script, which work well. But i want to only user can vote here. So Where I will add the code below OR any others way to do this please?

```
include_once("session.php");
if($session->logged_in){
    ***vote process work***
} else { echo' login for vote here';}
```

This is my html code

```
<div class="voting_kochi" id="1013">
  <div class="voting_btn">
    <div class="up_button">&nbsp;</div>
    <span class="up_votes">0</span></div>
  <div class="voting_btn">
    <div class="down_button">&nbsp;</div>
    <span class="down_votes">0</span></div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  //####### on page load, retrive votes for each content
  $.each( $('.voting_kochi'), function(){

    //retrive unique id from this voting_kochi element
    var unique_id = $(this).attr("id");

    //prepare post content
    post_data = {'unique_id':unique_id, 'vote':'fetch'};

    //send our data to "vote_process.php" using jQuery $.post()
    $.post('../vote_process.php', post_data,  function(response) {

            //retrive votes from server, replace each vote count text
            $('#'+unique_id+' .up_votes').text(response.vote_up); 
            $('#'+unique_id+' .down_votes').text(response.vote_down);
        },'json');
});


//####### on button click, get user vote and send it to vote_process.php using jQuery $.post().
$(".voting_kochi .voting_btn").click(function (e) {

    //get class name (down_button / up_button) of clicked element
    var clicked_button = $(this).children().attr('class');

    //get unique ID from voted parent element
    var unique_id   = $(this).parent().attr("id"); 

    if(clicked_button==='down_button') //user disliked the content
    {
        //prepare post content
        post_data = {'unique_id':unique_id, 'vote':'down'};

        //send our data to "vote_process.php" using jQuery $.post()
        $.post('../vote_process.php', post_data, function(data) {

            //replace vote down count text with new values
            $('#'+unique_id+' .down_votes').text(data);

        }).fail(function(err) { 

           //alert user about the HTTP server error
           alert(err.statusText); 
        });             

    }
    else if(clicked_button==='up_button') //user liked the content
    {
        //prepare post content
        post_data = {'unique_id':unique_id, 'vote':'up'};

        //send our data to "vote_process.php" using jQuery $.post()
        $.post('../vote_process.php', post_data, function(data) {

            //replace vote up count text with new values
            $('#'+unique_id+' .up_votes').text(data);               

        }).fail(function(err) {             
          //alert user about the HTTP server error
          alert(err.statusText); 
        });
    }

});
//end 

});
```

vote_process.php

$vote_up, 'vote_down'=>$vote_down);
                echo json_encode($send_response); //display json encoded values
                break;
        }
     }
     ?>

Comment: Are you sure you have wrote this code yourself if you don't know how or where to check if a user is logged in?

Comment: To be absolutely, positively sure that one user can vote only once you need some form of identification (user, password) and to register that the user has voted in a database.

Comment: Malcolm, I collect this code and modify for me. i will also try many ways to do that but can't.

Comment: SIT LCU, this is a COOKIE base script. I just want user can vote not how many times they can vote. Thanks